# XSLT: How to get position of an element among all such elements in the XML

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I get position/index of an element among all such elements in the XML document

For example, given below XML:

```
<root>
    <fac></fac>
    <pac>
        <sec>a</sec>
        <sec>b</sec>
    </pac>
    <pac>
        <sec>c</sec>
        <sec>d</sec>
    </pac>
    <sec>e</sec>
</root>
```

While processing `<pac>` nodes, such as with `<xsl:for-each select="pac">`, I need to get the position of `<sec>` node within entire XML document (irrespective of the level). So, I am looking to get position index for each `<sec>` as below:

```
<sec>a</sec> -> 1
<sec>b</sec> -> 2
<sec>c</sec> -> 3
<sec>d</sec> -> 4
<sec>e</sec> -> 5
```

Using `position()` function, it returns position relative to current parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xsl:number level="any"` e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="sec">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="pos">
              <xsl:number level="any"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcom

Comment: Is there a way to capture value of `xsl:number` in a variable? Actually, I have to use it inside `concat()` function, like below:
`<xsl:for-each select="pac">
    <tag><xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, $index)" /></tag>
</xsl:for-each>`

Comment: Use `<xsl:variable name="n"><xsl:number/></xsl:variable>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `count()` instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(.|preceding::sec)"/>
```

when you use the stylesheet with your input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sec">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', count(.|preceding::sec), ']')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it shows:

```
<root>
   <fac/>
   <pac>
      <sec>a</sec>[1]<sec>b</sec>[2]</pac>
   <pac>
      <sec>c</sec>[3]<sec>d</sec>[4]</pac>
   <sec>e</sec>[5]</root>
```

Comment: A couple of notes about performance. It obviously depends on the processor, but (a) I think a processor is much more likely to optimize `xsl:number` than `count(preceding::x)`, and (b) `count(preceding::x)+1` places less demand on the optimizer than `count(preceding::x|.)`. The naive strategy for both `xsl:number` and `count()`, of course, results in O(n^2) performance.

Comment: I agree, actually, Martin's answer is much more efficient given the input XML. There must be some code complications that the OP have not presented.